# How to make translatable Blog Paths from Blog module using i18n?

Tags: i18n-l10n

Now I only have 1 line for all blog paths.
i need to set up own blog path for each language in multilingual site

[image]

Comment: Could please make sure that "Locale" module is enabled and "Multilingual support" is enabled in the content type settings?

Comment: off course it is